# Rxjs map child objects plus parent field

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have this response from a http get

```
{
    "parents": [{
        "id": 1
        , "children": [{
                "name": "child1"
            }
            , {
                "name": "child2"
            }]
    }, {
        "id": 2
        , "children": [{
                "name": "child1"
        }]
    }]
}
```

and I have this interface

```
export interface Child {
    parentId: string
    , name: string
}
```

**Question**

Which map should I do to obtain an array of children (in the response of the subscription), with the name and the id of the parent?

```
getChildren(): Observable<Child[]> {    
    return this.http
        .get(API_URL)
        .//map function;
}
```

Or at least, tell me where to look to find some sort of answer

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single `map()` operator and then inside it use `Array.forEach()` and `Array.map()`:

```
const Observable = Rx.Observable;

data = {
  "parents": [{
    "id": 1
    , "children": [{
      "name": "child1"
    }
      , {
        "name": "child2"
      }]
  }, {
    "id": 2
    , "children": [{
      "name": "child1"
    }]
  }]
};

Observable.of(data)
  .map(data => {
    let results = [];
    data['parents'].forEach(item => {
      results = results.concat(item['children'].map(child => {
        return {
          'parentId': item.id,
          'name': child.name,
        };
      }));
    });

    return results;
  })
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

This will print the following (an array containing objects as a single emission):

```
[ { parentId: 1, name: 'child1' },
  { parentId: 1, name: 'child2' },
  { parentId: 2, name: 'child1' } ]
```

Comment: Although the answer gives what I quest (many thanks), I expended so much time because I was trying to do it only with the functions of rxjs, this is more an array work. Do you think is possible do it only with reactive prog? If is possible, will be more efficient? (Due the http response is an observable)

Comment: @WilliamArdila You could use RxJS `map` and `Observable.from` instead of `forEach()` but that would be unnecessary complicated and way less efficient.